# Problems compiling with gnuradio

Tags: installation, gnu, apt, gnuradio

I installed gnuradio on Ubuntu 18.04, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly. I try to build https://github.com/ccera-astro/spectro_radiometer, but it doesn't work. I received errors like:

```
>>> Converting from XML
ERROR:gnuradio.grc.core.FlowGraph:Failed to evaluate import expression "import spectro_helper  # embedded python module"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/grc/core/FlowGraph.py", line 234, in renew_namespace
    exec(expr, namespace)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/antonio/Downloads/spectro_radiometer/spectro_helper.py", line 97
    print "Setting mask at F %f position %d (%f)" % (float(f), i, incr*float(i))
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
ERROR:gnuradio.grc.core.FlowGraph:Failed to evaluate expression in module spectro_helper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/grc/core/FlowGraph.py", line 247, in renew_namespace
    exec(expr, module.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 97
    print "Setting mask at F %f position %d (%f)" % (float(f), i, incr*float(i))
```

Can anybody help me to install the proper version of gnuradio or to resolve these issues because I tried on MacOS as well and it didn't work.